# Focus on arson in New Mexico Constitution -- why? typo?

Tags: legal-history, history, new-mexico

In the State Constitution of New Mexico, Article II Section 24 Rights of Crime Victims, all the victims' rights are listed specifically for "a victim of arson" (see https://law.lclark.edu/live/files/7714-new-mexico). Why? Was this a typo that never got fixed? Did arson previously mean something more general than starting a fire? Did they want to particularly protect against arson for some reason? I assume that in reality other crime victims have similar protections, but why the focus on arson? Thx!

Answer (score 3):

The language is worded broader:

> "A victim of [list of crimes] or that victim's representative shall have the following rights as provided by law:"

The list is seemingly alphabetically, and covers besides arson injuring people, also aggravated arson & battery, misuse of explosives, negligent use of a deadly weapon, murder, [two other types of homicide], kidnapping, [various types of sexual misconduct], [two types of hit and run], [two types of child endangerment].

That is a closed list, that gives the victim or his representative (estate or legal guardian) the rights enumerated after.

Comment: Ooooh! Thank you. I read it as "a victim of arson resulting in: [list]". Got it. I was silly.